# Epoll randomly stops sending event for TcpStream

Tags: linux, rust, websocket, epoll

I got a tungstenite connection with a TcpStream set to non-blocking and a timerfd connected to a epoll fd, for some reason the tcpstreams fd events randomly stops(it's not because of no more data is being sent) and no debugging have helped me find the problem.
Tungstenite don't report anything wrong with the connection, there's just no more events for the rfd variable.

```
pub fn run_realtime_session(...) {
    let mut shutdown = false;

    let efd = epoll::create(true).unwrap();

    // Set up timer
    let mut timer = timerfd::TimerFd::new_custom(timerfd::ClockId::Realtime, true, false).unwrap();
    let tfd = timer.as_raw_fd();
    let timer_event = epoll::Event::new(epoll::Events::EPOLLIN, tfd.try_into().unwrap());
    epoll::ctl(efd, epoll::ControlOptions::EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tfd, timer_event).unwrap();
    timer.set_state(
        timerfd::TimerState::Periodic {
            current: std::time::Duration::from_millis(50),
            interval: std::time::Duration::from_millis(50),
        },
        timerfd::SetTimeFlags::Default,
    );

    // Set up reader
    let rfd = reader.as_raw_fd().unwrap();
    let read_event = epoll::Event::new(
        epoll::Events::EPOLLIN | epoll::Events::EPOLLET,
        rfd.try_into().unwrap(),
    );
    epoll::ctl(efd, epoll::ControlOptions::EPOLL_CTL_ADD, rfd, read_event).unwrap();
    let mut events = [epoll::Event::new(epoll::Events::empty(), 0); 10];

    while !shutdown {
        let res = epoll::wait(efd, -1, &mut events).unwrap();
        for event in events {
            if event.data as i32 == tfd {
                timer.read();
                ...
            } else if event.data as i32 == rfd {
                match reader.read() {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to call `reader.read()` in a loop until you receive `EAGAIN`? It's a bit hard to comment since you don't show the type of `reader` or how you actually read.
(And I do wonder why you're trying to implement this yourself. Using mio or io_uring should provide similarly low-level control with fewer pitfalls. Or, get the hammer and use tokio.)

Comment: @Caesar It's just a wrapper over a tungstenite client, so reader.read calls read_message(), I'll try looping until the non-block error is thrown.  Mostly for education

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have solved it by putting reader.read() in a loop until std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock is thrown.

Comment: Might wanna have a look at the epoll man page, especially the part around "Since the read operation done in 4 does not consume the whole buffer data, the call to epoll_wait(2) done in step 5 might block  indefinitely."